# Associated Product not showing the different price

Tags: magento

I have just added a product and everything works fine. The product is a top with different attributes: size and color.

However I want to have reduced price on one of the different colors like in a sale, so I went into the associated products section and changed the price. However, whenever I go to the website and click on the color of the reduced price top, it still shows the original price and not the one I just changed.

How can I get it to show the price I changed it to?

Comment: Can you provide more details Arken?
What is your magento version?
Have you tried to run price reindex?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Out of the box the only way to do this is via the price offsets for each configurable option under "Super product attributes configuration" as shown in the attached image:

[image: Configurable price offset per option]

Otherwise, you can use an extension such as [Simple Configurable Products](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html) http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Answer (score 1):

Go to system > Index Management and reindex Product Prices data

Comment: hi, i have tried to reindex the product prices, but no luck, when i got to the main tshirt it is £40, then when i select the colour white and medium size it should turn to £32 but it still stays at £40

Answer (score -1):

It sounds like you are using a configurable product with associated simple products.  As far as I'm aware Magento only refreshes the product price for bundle product types.

I have seen a lot of people recommending [this module](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html).

Comment: I was wondering if i need to reindex the data, do you think that could do it?